# Getting Objects that are Nil in another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

So I have a table of lots. I need to get every lot that doesn't have a image_container linked.  I figure the best way to do this would be a join that would only give me lots that don't have a image container. The default `Join` by Rails does the exact opposite of this. What would be my best route to finding lots that don't have an image?

```
@lots = @event.lots.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").page params[:page]
@lots = @lots.joins(:image_containers)
```

What would be the best way to get lots that don't have an `image_container`?

Image_container is a polymorphic object.  So Image_container has a imageable_type of "Lot" and imageable_id is the Lot's id.

image_container model:

```
belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :image, :inverse_of => :image_containers
```

event model:

```
has_many :image_containers, :as => :imageable, :inverse_of => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :images, :through => :image_containers
```

Lot model:

```
has_many :image_containers, :as => :imageable, :inverse_of => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :images, :through => :image_containers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just find the lots that have their image_container_id set to `nil`:

```
@lots = @lots.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN image_containers ON image_containers.imageable_id = lots.id AND image_containers.imageable_type = 'Lot' WHERE image_containers.id IS NULL")
```

Hopefully this works, I'm not very familiar with join queries myself. You can test if this works by adding `.map{|lot| lot.image_containers.count}` to the end of the query to check that the returned array only contains zeroes.

Comment: I should have put that the image_container is polymorphic.  so it would be belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
 belongs_to :image, :inverse_of => :image_containers and in event it has has_many :image_containers, :as => :imageable, :inverse_of => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy